# Example of a group where $o(a)$ and $o(b)$ are finite but $o(ab)$ is infinite

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, examples-counterexamples

Let G be a group and $a,b \in G$. It is given that $o(a)$ and $o(b)$ are finite. Can you give an example of a group where $o(ab)$ is infinite?

Comment: Presumably $\circ(a)$ refers to the order of $a$, right?

Comment: That's unusual notation if it's supposed to be the order of an element.  Probably what you have seen is $o(a)$, where the $o$ is the first letter of 'order'.

Comment: Also related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/279199/on-order-of-elements-of-a-infinite-group/279218#279218

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The standard example is the infinite dihedral group.

Consider the group of maps on $\mathbf{Z}$ 
$$
D_{\infty} = \{ x \mapsto \pm x + b : b \in \mathbf{Z}  \}.
$$
Consider the maps
$$
\sigma: x \mapsto -x,
\qquad
\tau: x \mapsto -x + 1,
$$
both of order $2$. Their composition
$$
\tau \circ \sigma (x) = \tau(\sigma(x)) : x \mapsto x + 1
$$
has infinite order.

Answer (score 33):

Probably you have seen this effect: mirrors on two opposite walls of a room.

[image]

Take two parallel hyperplanes in $\mathbb R^n$.  Reflection in each of them is an isometry of order 2.  But their composition is a translation of infinite order.

Comment: I like this answer a lot!

Comment: Upon seeing the question my first reaction was to post this as an example. Then I look closer and see that @AndreasCaranti beat me to it. And you too! I feel so "ninja'ed". Nice pic demonstrating the effect though. I mean, wish I could give both of you a second upvote (Well, Clayton, too).

Comment: Interesting: even after the question is closed, I can still receive up-votes and badges for this answer.

Comment: Wow, your answer is genially. Congratulations!

Answer (score 19):

Consider the matrices $$A=\left(\begin{array}[cc] .1 & -1\\ 0 & -1\end{array}\right)\quad\text{and}\quad B=\left(\begin{array}[cc].1&0\\ 0 & -1\end{array}\right).$$ You can check that each have order $2$, but their product gives $$(AB)^n=\left(\begin{array}[cc] .1 & n\\ 0 & 1\end{array}\right),$$a matrix without finite order.

Comment: It is interesting to note that if you consider $A,B$ as elements of $\text{PSL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$, and consider them with their normal action on the upper half plane then your answer is really the same as Andreas Caranti's.

Comment: See please http://math.stackexchange.com/a/316041/8581. I made another. ;-) and +10 for you.

Answer (score 9):

If $\circ(a)$ is the order of $a$, usually denoted $|a|$, looking at permutations of $\mathbb{N}$ are an easy way to find an example.

For example consider the permutations:

$$ a = (12)(34)(56)...$$
$$ b = (23)(45)(67)...$$

It isn't hard to see that both $a$ and $b$ have order 2, but consider the image of $1$ under $(ab)^n$ to see that the order of $ab$ is infinite.

Answer (score 4):

If there's any example at all, then

$$ G = \langle a,b \mid a^m , b^n \rangle $$

is an example for some positive integers $m,n$. I assert that *every* choice with $m,n > 1$ is an example.

Comment: In addition: it can be proved using normal form for free products since $G= \langle a \mid a^m \rangle \ast \langle b \mid b^n \rangle \simeq \mathbb{Z}_m \ast \mathbb{Z}_n$.

Answer (score 4):

Every direct plane rotation (of angle $2\theta$) is the composite of two orthogonal reflections with fixed lines making an angle of $\theta$. If $2\theta/2\pi$ is irrational, then the rotation of angle $2\theta$ has infinite order.