# Finding $A,B\in SL_2(\Bbb{Z})$ of finite order with the property that $AB=C$ where the order of $C$ is infinite.

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, matrices

I'm trying to think of two matrices $A,B\in SL_2(\Bbb{Z})$ of finite order ($A^n=B^m=I$) with 
the property that $AB=C$ where the order of $C$ is infinite.

I guess that just by trial and error I could find two of those matrices, but I would like to find those in a little bit more sophisticated way. What would be a good strategy ?

Comment: Its one of the answers here --->   http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/314850/example-of-a-group-where-oa-and-ob-are-finite-but-oab-is-infinite/314857#comment681871_314857

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides to what @Clayton pointed at above link you can take the following matrices as well:  $$A=\left(\begin{array}[cc] .0 & -1\\ 1 &  0\end{array}\right)\quad\text{and}\quad B=\left(\begin{array}[cc].0&1\\ -1 & -1\end{array}\right)$$ You can check that $A^4=I=B^3$ but $AB$ has infinite order. This means that $tSL_2(\mathbb Z)$ including of all torsion elements of the group is not a subgroup.