# Find $A,B\in GL_2(\mathbb{C})$ such that $A$ and $B$ have finite order but $AB$ has an infinite order.

Tags: matrices, group-theory

What type of matrices in $GL_2(\mathbb{C})$ have finite order?

In particular, I am trying to solve the following problem.

Find $A,B\in GL_2(\mathbb{C})$ such that $A$ and $B$ have finite order but $AB$ has an infinite order.

How to proceed?

Comment: See here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/316030/finding-a-b-in-sl-2-bbbz-of-finite-order-with-the-property-that-ab-c-whe?rq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding $A,B\in SL_2(\Bbb{Z})$ of finite order with the property that $AB=C$ where the order of $C$ is infinite.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/316030/finding-a-b-in-sl-2-bbbz-of-finite-order-with-the-property-that-ab-c-whe)

Answer (score 1):

Any "reflection" matrix with eigenvalues $1$ and $-1$ will have finite order (viz. $2$). Such a matrix has trace zero and determinant $-1$ so has the form
$$\pmatrix{a&b\\c&-a}$$
with $a^2+bc=1$.
This gives a lot of possibilities for $A$ and $B$. Surely it can't
be hard to write down some $A$ and $B$ such that $AB$ has infinite order?