# Give an example of a nonabelian group in which a product of elements of finite order can have infinite order.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, examples-counterexamples, abelian-groups

So, I let a,b be elements in such a group. So |a|=n and |b|=m, n and m are finite. But |ab| needs to be infinite, but since |ab|=lcm(n,m), how can that be possible?

Comment: The result you quote is not correct. In an **Abelian** group, the order of $ab$ is $\le$ the lcm of the orders of $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Some related posts: [Example of a group where $o(a)$ and $o(b)$ are finite but $o(ab)$ is infinite](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/314850/example-of-a-group-where-oa-and-ob-are-finite-but-oab-is-infinite) and [Examples and further results about the order of the product of two elements in a group](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/41303/examples-and-further-results-about-the-order-of-the-product-of-two-elements-in-a)

Comment: Where does this problem come from? Is it from a book? From an assignment?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take the free group on letters $a,b$ with the sole relations that $a^2=b^2=1$.  Now $ab$ has infinite order, since $$abababab\cdots ab \neq 1$$

Comment: Can you explain more on this? I don't quite understand.

Comment: @safaqfwrq Do you know how to define groups via *generators* and *relations* - that is, are you familiar with notation like "$\langle a, b\vert a^2, b^2\rangle$"?

Comment: This is in some sense a restatement of the question: it's true that if $a^2 = 1$ and $b^2 = 1$ then $ab$ has infinite order iff it's true in this universal example. So you have not yet answered the question. You're implicitly using the fact that you think you know how to solve the word problem in this group...

Answer (score 14):

Consider group of all permutations of $\mathbb{Z}$; permutation group on $\geq 3$ letters is always non-abelian.

Consider $\sigma(x)=-x+1$ and $\tau(x)=-x+2$, the two permutations of $\mathbb{Z}$.

- Show that $\tau\circ\tau=\sigma\circ\sigma=I$, hence order of $\sigma,\tau$ is $2$.
- Find $\sigma\circ \tau$.
- Is it of finite order?

Comment: This simple answer (+1) has a nice relation to mine: Two reflections on parallel lines give a translation. This is then just the one-dimensional discrete case.

Answer (score 9):

Compose two reflections on the plane and you get a rotation. Reflections have order 2. The rotation can have arbitrary order, including infinite.

Comment: I'm trying to imagine a rotation of infinite order. I think rotation through an irrational number of degrees, or a rational number of radians would work, right?

Comment: Right. By the way, another interesting case is when the reflections are on parallel lines, which gives a translation (see Groups' answer).

Comment: An irrational number of degrees will work.  An irrational number of radians might not.  A rational number of radians will work though!

Answer (score 3):

Matrices, invertible ones are a group under multiplication and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/41308/197853) is a good example