# Give an example of an infinite group generated by two elements of finite order

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Give an example of an infinite group generated by two elements of finite order. I can't think of any on top of my head.

Comment: Infinite dihedral group?  $\text{SL}_2(\Bbb Z)$?

Comment: Exact duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/a/314890/442