# For $A,B \in \mathscr{M}_{2\times2}(\mathbb{Q}) $ of finite order, show that $AB$ has infinite order

Tags: matrices, group-theory, cyclic-groups

Let $G$ be the group $ ( \mathscr{M}_{2\times2}(\mathbb{Q}) , \times ) $ of nonsingular matrices.

Let $ A = \left (
\begin{matrix}
 0 & -1 \\ 
 1 & 0 
\end{matrix}
\right ) $, the order of $A$ is $4$;

Let $ B = \left (
\begin{matrix}
 0 & 1 \\ 
 -1 & -1 
\end{matrix}
\right ) $, the order of $B$ is $3$.

Show that $AB$ has infinite order.

---

The only reasoning possible here is by contradiction as $G$ is not abelian. And so I tried, but I got stuck before any concrete development.

Any hints are welcome,
Thanks.

Comment: That M's got swag.

Comment: @GitGud `\mathscr` is where it's at

Comment: @GitGud it is not for the sake of beauty, but specially used.

Comment: The answer by amWhy (at the duplicate) contains the answers given below.

Comment: Also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/279199/on-order-of-elements-of-a-infinite-group?noredirect=1&lq=1) has the same matrices as above in the answer by mrs.

Comment: @DietrichBurde the question may be duplicate, because I didn't verify actually. But about the other post, maybe we had the same reference book (Graduate Algebra, by Hungerford) but the question is about linear groups this time, and they are not explained at the same stage at all here. no way I could find these to merge the posts.

Comment: Did you read the answer by mrs? Actually, the question on the order of a product in matrix groups is one of the most frequent duplicates for abstract algebra. Maybe I did not choose the best duplicate with respect to the title.

Comment: @DietrichBurde You are right. Though I'm surprised he gave the exact same example as answer. Sorry about being totally impatient to dive into it. I generally do check the subject.

Comment: No problem. I just wanted to say that this type of example with two matrices in $GL_2(\Bbb{Z})$ is really popular...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We compute
$$
AB = \pmatrix{1&1\\0&1}
$$
We can prove (using induction, for instance) that
$$
(AB)^n = \pmatrix{1&n\\0&1}
$$
Since there is no positive $n$ for which $(AB)^n$ is the identity matrix, we see that $AB$ is of infinite order.

Comment: Same answer, faster by the way than mine.

Comment: @vidyarthi and how can we this fast conclude that $(AB)^n = \left (
\begin{matrix}
 1 & n \\ 
 0 & 1 
\end{matrix}
\right ) $?

Comment: @freehumorist you just need to show that
$$
\pmatrix{1&1\\0&1} \pmatrix{1&n\\0&1}
 = \pmatrix{1&n+1\\0&1}$$

Answer (score 4):

You have $AB=\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$ And $(AB)^n=\begin{pmatrix}1&n\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$ by induction. Therefore, its order in the given group is infinite.