# Conditions for a finitely generated group with finite ordered generators

Tags: group-theory, group-presentation, finitely-generated

What are the conditions for a finitely generated group $G$ with finite ordered generators say $a_1, a_2,...,a_n$ to be finite?

Note:I know that if $G$ is abelian, then it is finite. Are there any other known results that I can use here?

Comment: $\Bbb{Z},+$ is abelian and finitely generated (by $1$) but not finite. So it seems that every generator should have finite order, but is that sufficient?

Answer (score 0):

In general, you have to require much more than generators to have finite orders. For instance, even if you take a 2-step nilpotent group, you would have to require all the commutators of the generators to have finite order (in addition to the generators themselves).

Edit: The above is not right, as Derek Holt noted: Since the subset of finite order elements of a nilpotent group is a subgroup, if a group $G$ is nilpotent and all its generators are of finite order, then every element of $G$ has finite order, then $G$ is finite.

In order to prove this, note that all the members of the derived series of $G$ are finitely-generated. Then, we argue argue by induction on the length of the derived series of $G$: The center $Z(G)$ of $G$ is finite, since it is a finitely generated abelian and torsion. By the induction hypothesis, $G/Z(G)$ is also finite. Hence, $G$ is finite as well.

Once you leave the realm of solvable groups, things become very complicated. For instance, it is not even enough to assume that *all elements of your group* have finite order, for $G$ to be finite. Read about [Burnside problem] (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burnside's_problem) to find more about it.

Comment: I don't think that's right. A nilpotent group generated by finitely many elements of finite order is finite. This is not true for solvable groups however, as shown by the infinite dihedral group.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/79474 for a proof of the claim about nilpotent groups.

Comment: Oh, you a right of course: I forgot that the subset of torsion element in a nilpotent group is a subgroup.