# If $G=\langle\{a_i\}_{i=1}^r\rangle$ is nilpotent with $|a_i|=m_i$, show that $|G|$ divides a power of $\prod_{i=1}^rm_i$ and is finite.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, nilpotent-groups

[image]

use this notation for the following $\textbf{Theorem}$  -

$\textbf{notation}-$ $G^n$ is the subgroup generated by $n$th power of elements of $G$

$\textbf{Theorem}$- In a finitely generated nilpotent group, $\cap{G^p}$, for any infinite set of primes, is finite,(follows by a paper of  HIGMAN) does it help me to prove this question above. I don't think so.

Is it true, that a group generated by finite elements of finite order is finite. If it is true then  to prove $G$ is finite in the problem is easy, and don not require nilpotency. But it should not be true, but what can be an example?

Comment: [Tarski monsters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski_monster_group) are examples of finitely generated groups whose generators have finite order.

Comment: so we need nilpotency to say $G$ is finite. How can i approach this problem?

Comment: Use induction on the nilpotence class, and consider the central quotient in the non-abelian case.

Comment: I can't use induction, until I show $G$ is finite

Comment: The fact that $G$ is finite is proved in the answer by Artuto Magidin to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/79474 Since it is finite, it is the direct product of its Sylow subgroups, and it is easy to see that the only promes dividing $|G|$ are those dividing the order of one of the generators. (And the proof does use induction!)

Comment: @BhaskarVashishth The induction is on nilpotence class, which is finite by assumption.

Comment: ohh yes. Induction on class. I am still reading Arturo's proof. let see which one will be easier.

Comment: @DerekHolt by Artuto's Proof only significant thing for me which I could find out was that in his theorem he proves that product of two elements of finite order is of finite order, which in my case tells that $G$ has all its elements of finite order. But $G$ can still be infinite? what I am missing, to see $G$ is finite??

Comment: That's an easy induction on the class. The torsion subgroup true is finite for abelian groups and, for nonabelian groups, by induction both $G/Z(G)$ and $Z(G)$ are finite, so $G$ is finite.